# php in_array - unexpected behavior

Tags: php, arrays

Not sure why this is happening, but my script doesn't seem to be able to return true for in_array more than once...

```
$saved = '15,22';    
$set = explode(",",$saved); //results in Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 22 )
```

Then, I query the database:

```
$result = pg_query("SELECT did,vid,iid,value FROM demographicValues");
if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($r = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
     $demo[$r['did']][$r['vid']]['value'] = $r['value'];
     if(in_array($r['vid'], $set)) {
       $demo[$r['did']][$r['vid']]['status'] = 1;
     }
  }
} else...
```

If I print_r $demo, you can see that the vid 22 is in there, so, I'm not understanding why the status isn't being set accordingly?

```
    Array
    (
        [Mant] => Array
            (
                [15] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Proper
                        [checked] => 1
                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => Parish
                    )
        [Comp] => Array
            (
                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 65 - 70
                    )

                [23] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 35 - 50
                    )
        )

)
```

Note that I also tried array_intersect and array_flip on $set, then isset...

Comment: There may be some spaces or other invisible characters messing up the code. Can you use `var_dump` rather than `print_r`? It'll put quotes around the strings and tell us the number of variables.

Comment: if you add `var_dump($r['vid'], $set)` immediately before 'in_array' line - what does it say?

Comment: Thank you so much... Yes, the $set did have some unnecessary spaces, and using trim got it to work... Thanks!

Comment: normally, I'd recommend using an associative array over `in_array` for performance reasons(`$set = array_flip(explode(',', $saved)); ... if (isset($set[$r['vid']]))`), but `$set` is so short it won't make much of a difference; `in_array` might even be faster for just a few elements. Another approach is to set the status in the query: `SELECT did,vid,iid,value, vid IN ($saved) AS status FROM demographicValues;`

Comment: @Sterofrog and @n00b0101: suggest reposting comment as answer and select as correct answer so the question no longer shows up on unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

By default `in_array` also checks the types.
See the parameter `strict` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php.

In your code `$r['vid']` is an integer and the exploded string is still a string. So just use the same types or use:

```
if(in_array($r['vid'], $set, false)) ...
```

Comment: by default php will _not_ check the types